# Is OnTouchListener faster than OnClickListener?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm making an Android 2D game, which is multiplayer and two players use the same screen...

Each user has a couple of buttons to control their player, and sometimes they should click those buttons as fast as they can... And that's where I have problems with!

I tested the app on a real device, and (I'm not sure about this, but) I think when both users click multiple buttons at the same time, some of these clicks won't work! I can see that players move slowly...

Is this because of the device (which is a Samsung Galaxy S3)? Or because of the `OnClickListener` I used? Is `OnTouchListener` better in this case? Or they're the same?

Comment: Checkout [Mastering the Android Touch System](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) on Youtube.

Comment: A click event needs a down and up action. If the up action happens outside of the button or view it won't trigger a click event. But certain touch events probably fire even without a touch leave type event. Might be an issue if clicks happen a little too fast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For an `OnClickListener` to be called the user must *press* then *release* the button. 
With an `OnTouchListener` you can check for an <kbd>ACTION_DOWN</kbd> event, and this means your application will not need to wait for 2 events before it can react. So *in theory* the `OnTouchListener` should be *"faster"* if you implement it right.

Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 5):

onTouchListener is faster than on clickListener

**onTouchListener**:-Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a touch event is dispatched to  view. The callback will be invoked before the touch event is given to the view.

**onClickListener**:-Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when a view is clicked.

If you really care about is touch or not then use onClickListener