# Onclick has a delay

Tags: android

I have an app, and i'm trying to make a View move. However, when I press the Right button, there is a six second delay.

I've tried changing the button name so far.

```
btnRighto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View righto) {
                x += 100;
                first.setImageResource(R.drawable.cata);
                ObjectAnimator d = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(first, "translationX", x);
                d.setDuration(50);
                d.start();
                first.setImageResource(R.drawable.catb);
                first.setImageResource(R.drawable.catb);

                first.setImageResource(R.drawable.catb);

            }

        });
```

It works but there's a long delay but sometimes crashes the app.

Comment: Is there possibly something else on the main thread that could be putting this on hold until that finishes?

Comment: how big is `R.drawable.cata` and `R.drawable.catb`? maybe they are too heavy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach,

you can try with `OnTouchListener`  & handle button with durations

that can achieve all the things that you have done in `OnClickListener`

**OnClickListener** - is used for a basic purpose, when we just need a click from a user i.e., click of a button, no drag or gestures on the screen

**OnTouchListener** is basically a more fine-tuned control than OnClickListener. It performs and action on a press/ release on the screen It allows a user with a combination of the move,down-touch,up-touch, finger drag or any movement gesture on the screen

[onTouchListener Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755748/is-ontouchlistener-faster-than-onclicklistener)